# Is this a good leadership strategy?

Tags: professionalism, communication, unprofessional-behavior, leadership, social-media

So I am relative new in my career, and I just secured a long-term internship with a small company. I have 2 leaders, lets call them X (the guy) and Y (the woman)

The guy rarely chit-chats-- he seems super focused on his work, he always dresses professionally, he seems up-to-date with the latest developments in his fields, the only time he ever talked to me was when I was giving my presentation on some tech I was researching

The woman in contrast is always talking about personal stuff-- her family life, her living situation, her political views. I can ever search up her social media accounts ( they came up when I was googling her involvement in a deal) and know all about her family, her dog etc.

Conversely, he seems very private...he only has a LinkedIn, all other social media is private. You can find nothing about his family, his political view, whether he is married etc.

So which approach can help me accelerate in my career?

Comment: I'm confused, is this some monte hall situation where you have to pick either of the doors and stick with it forever ? Or what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 1):

What works for you, and you are comfortable with, works for you and is comfortable. Neither will particularly accelerate or hold back your career. You can change your mind at any time, or interact differently with different people, or...

Not everything matters.

Answer (score 0):

> So which approach can help me accelerate in my career?

Both, neither, one of them. People are people. How chatty they are has no direct impact on how successful they are.

Based on these characteristics there is no way for us to guess which one will be successful 10 years from now. Or which one will be a failure. In fact they both could be. Or they could be someplace in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

> So which approach can help me accelerate in my career?

The most important thing is to do a very good job in every project that you work on. Make sure you deliver high quality products. Also, keep good work relationship with all your coworkers and your managers. Get along well with everyone.

---

**About the ways your 2 team leads talk and display info on social media:**

You can either be talkative or mostly focus on work, or be somewhere in the middle. Is is fine as long as you are being nice, polite, friendly, and respectful to everyone.

Your team leads are successful at work because they do a good job at work. Their success is not really a result of their posting lots of info or zero info on social media about their private life.

Answer (score 0):

Neither approach will accelerate your career in particular. They're personal rather than professional.

Accelerate your career by networking with the right people in the right way. Gaining certifications etc,.

Answer (score 0):

#### Being yourself is the best policy

Don't try to adjust how you act to move your career.  Obviously if you have some type of personality defect this might be bad advice, but generally acting normal is the best policy (whatever is normal to you).  Your two business contacts both act differently, and that's fine.  If you are a private person and try to somehow be open about personal issues it won't work - it will be forced an unnatural.

I suggest that religion and politics are best left out of business relationships, but open versus private is up to you.